# YouTube API Key in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, android-youtube-api

1. I am using a PhoneGap Android application which shows some content and then a playlist which shows some 20 videos.
2. My file uses this : https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId="+t+"&key=my_api_key_from_console"
3. I have registered the application, and incorporated the API key in my js file. The app - to be exact, the html file- is working and shows the videos, author details and thumbnails, from the API key. (I can see the requests details from Developer console.)
4. I have digitally signed the apk, created SHA-1 fingerprint and pasted in the Console.
5. But, when I add the SHA-1 fingerprint to the API key, the results (videos, thumbnails and author details ) don't show up, in local machine. I tested in android device, same result, no videos show up.
6. The app does not use YouTube Android Player jar file.

What could be the reason? Is it must to have  YouTube Android Player API ?

Comment: hm i think you mistaken api for youtube and api for signed apk

Comment: Can you please explain this further ?

Comment: use your browser api key, dont use android api key

Comment: Thanks, I will try browser key !

Comment: I submitted the app using Browser key . But, the app got rejected with the reason 'Violation of YouTube or YouTube API Terms of Service'. How to solve this fingerprint issue?

Comment: did you input any URL in `Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites) `?

Comment: No, I left the box blank.

Comment: @JackFingleton Did you make it work with browser key? Have you tried with a Server Key?

Comment: sorry for this delayed reponse, yes, the browser key works

Comment: How did you get this to work with a browser key? Did you have to accept requests from any refererer? Did you try using an android key API?

Comment: @Yaron - I just filled in the browser key details and left the referrer box blank

Comment: Thank. I prefer to not do that as then anyone can use my key. I'll try to see if there are other options.